# Prestashop's save button don’t work (in all the tabs)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

My prestashop save button for products only works on some tabs

I had:

- Informations
- Price
- SEO
- Associations
- Combinations
- Quantities
- Virtual Product
- Images (Not working save button)
- Functions
- Tabs (Not working save button)
- Product Video (Not working save button)
- Booking (Not working save button)

... and anothers (that don’t save as well)

**My infos**

PHP 5.6.40
Memory Limit: 256M
Prestashop 1.6.1.0

**I already tried:**

Disable some modules (most of them), don’t succeed.

I delete

```
submitHandler: function(form)
{ form.submit(); }
```

From /admin/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl
and the another tabs can save now, not all of them (pricing, informations now works).

Update php version on cpanel, dont suceed.

desactive non-active modules and desactive overrides, dont suceed either.

**What i see**

The save button, get a load from all the product info, if i, click on those tabs who dont save (even in the 'tabs') change anything and click on save, before the 'save button' get loaded, its saves!

What can i do?

Comment: I had a booking module installed on a 1.6 version too. That also gave problems. Back then only saving in FireFox worked. Can you check that?

Comment: Hi friend, i alredy use firefox, so, it do not work. I try Chrome, firefox, opera and IE. Still not saving.